Issue with Nested Dropdown Menus in ASP.NET Core Razor Pages
enter image description here
I'm facing an issue with nested dropdown menus in my ASP.NET Core Razor Pages application. The outermost dropdown menu works fine, but the child dropdowns are shown inside the parent dropdown, causing a horizontal scrollbar to appear on the x-axis. I want each dropdown menu to be displayed at the page level itself.
I have a Razor Pages view where I'm rendering a horizontal navigation menu with nested dropdowns. Here's a simplified version of my code:
<style>
    .dropdown-menu {
        /* Other CSS styles... */
        max-height: 550px;
        overflow-y: auto;
    }

    .dropdown-submenu .dropdown-menu {
        /* Other CSS styles... */
    }

    .dropdown-submenu:hover .dropdown-menu {
        /* Other CSS styles... */
        overflow-y: auto;
    }
</style>

<header>
    <!-- Other header content... -->

    <body>
        <ul class="horizontal-list">
            @foreach (var menuItem in Model.MenuItems.Where(m => m.parentId == null))
            {
                <li>
                    <a class="dropdown-toggle" href="#" role="button" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">@menuItem.formName</a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                        @foreach (var subMenuItem in Model.MenuItems.Where(m => m.parentId == menuItem.formID))
                        {
                            @if (Model.MenuItems.Any(m => m.parentId == subMenuItem.formID))
                            {
                                <li class="dropdown-submenu">
                                    <a class="dropdown-item dropdown-toggle" href="#">@subMenuItem.formName</a>
                                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                        @foreach (var subsubMenuItem in Model.MenuItems.Where(m => m.parentId == subMenuItem.formID))
                                        {
                                            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="@subsubMenuItem.formUrl">@subsubMenuItem.formName</a></li>
                                        }
                                    </ul>
                                </li>
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="@subMenuItem.formUrl">@subMenuItem.formName</a></li>
                            }
                        }
                    </ul>
                </li>
            }
        </ul>

        @section scripts{
            <script>
                function validateGo() {
                    var role = document.getElementById("role").value;
                    if (role === "") {
                        alert("Please select a role to switch");
                        return false;
                    }
                    else return true;
                }

            </script>
            <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0-alpha1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-wrlFy0zBbPVHA+FsEutKZnp8P/qEnCc3CTN7IUUzHQRdoqwefCGsM/lfmR4o4il7" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        }
    </body>
</header>


What I Tried:
I have implemented a horizontal navigation menu with nested dropdowns in my ASP.NET Core Razor Pages application. Each dropdown menu has multiple levels of submenus.
Expected Outcome:
I expected each dropdown menu (including submenus) to be displayed at the page level itself, rather than inside its parent dropdown. This would allow users to navigate the menu structure without encountering horizontal scrollbars or overlapping dropdowns.
Actual Result:
However, when I hover over a parent menu item to access its submenu, the submenu appears inside the parent dropdown, causing a horizontal scrollbar to appear on the x-axis. This behavior makes navigation difficult for users, especially when there are multiple levels of submenus.
I have attempted to modify the CSS and HTML code to ensure that each dropdown menu is displayed at the page level, but I have not been successful in resolving the issue.
Any insights or suggestions on how to achieve the desired outcome would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!
